# Downsample PCLPointCloud2 keeping it organized

Tags: c++, computer-vision, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to downsample a `pcl::PCLPointCloud2 points` that I get from a Kinect One (which is an organized point cloud: `points.width = 512` and `points.height = 424`). By using a `pcl::VoxelGrid` the resulting downsampled point cloud is no more organized (`output_points.height = 1`) but I need it to be organized for Normal Estimation.

Is there any way to downsample preserving the organized structure or at least is it possible to re-organize the unorganized output of the VoxelGrid?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you say a point cloud has to be organized for estimating normals? This is not the case, see for example [PCL documentation on estimating surface normals](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php).

Comment: @mikkola The module of pointcloud elaboration is done by others and I can't modify it. It makes use of Normal Estimation using Integral Images for faster results. So I really have no choice but to preserve the organized structure of the pointcloud after downsampling (downsampling is also necessary).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245726/pcl-downsample-with-pclvoxelgrid

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to down sample the organized cloud iterate over it and pick every nth point in both rows and columns. Such as

```
int scale = 2;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::your_point_type> down_sampled_cloud; 
down_sampled_cloud.width = original_cloud.width / scale;
down_sampled_cloud.height = original_cloud.height / scale;

for( int ii = 0; ii < original_cloud.height; ii+=scale){
    for( int jj = 0; jj < original_cloud.width; jj+=scale ){
    down_sampled_cloud.push_back(original_cloud.at(ii,jj));

    }
}
```

No way to guarantee that voxel grid downsampling will preserve the structure.